# Cannot play the complete sound

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
MediaPlayer player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
bool playing = false;

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
    {
        if (label5.Text == "Waiting 01.wav")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No wav loaded");
            return;
        }
        pictureBox6.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
        try
        {
            player.Open(new Uri(label37.Text));
            player.Volume = (double)trackBar4.Value / 100;
            playing = true;
            player.Play();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
        }
    }
}

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
    {
        pictureBox6.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
        player.Stop();
        player.Close();
        playing = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the .wav file won't play complete just a fraction of it.

It should play complete when the key D1 is pressed until it's released.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyDown event is repeating.  One solution is to simply return right away if it is a repeat key down.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.IsRepeat) return;
    // ...
```

Comment: It throws me an error: Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs' doesn't contain a definition of 'IsRepeat'

Comment: plz help me fix that error.

Comment: What version of CLR are you using?  e.IsRepeat works correctly with CLR4.0 but may not in other enviornments.  The main idea is that the sound plays shortly becuase the key down repeats over and over when the key is held down.  Each time it starts to play the sound over.  Try adding a flag, i.e.:bool _bKeyIsDown = false;protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (_bIsDown) return;
_bIsDown = true;
// play sound; 
base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
base.OnKeyUp(e);
_bIsDown = false;
}

Comment: I've found that the sounds won't play fast with this... you hold a key and it plays normally but when you switch to another key it takes a while for the sound to play making it sloppy. Is there something i could make to fix this? Iam guessing the problem is here: if (_bIsDown) return;